# Mono MonoDevelop install fails on CentOS 6

Tags: centos

im doing this, on CentOS 6.4 64bits:

```
yum install bison gettext glib2 freetype fontconfig libpng libpng-devel libX11 libX11-devel glib2-devel libgdi* libexif glibc-devel urw-fonts java unzip gcc gcc-c++ automake autoconf libtool make bzip2 wget

cd /usr/local/src

wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-3.4.0.tar.bz2

tar jxf mono-3.4.0.tar.bz2

cd mono-3.4.0

./configure --prefix=/opt/mono

make && make install

yum install glib2-devel libX11-devel pixman-devel fontconfig-devel freetype-devel libexif-devel libjpeg-devel libtiff-devel libpng-devel giflib-devel

cd /usr/src

wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/libgdiplus/libgdiplus-2.10.9.tar.bz2

tar -xvjf libgdiplus-2.10.9.tar.bz2

cd libgdiplus-2.10.9

./configure --prefix=/opt/mono

make && make install

yum install gtk2-devel libglade2-devel

cd /usr/src

PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/mono/lib/pkgconfig

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH

wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/gtk-sharp212/gtk-sharp-2.12.21.tar.gz

tar -vzxf gtk-sharp-2.12.21.tar.gz

cd gtk-sharp-2.12.21

./configure --prefix=/opt/mono

make && make install

yum install pango-devel atk-devel libgnome-devel libgnomecanvas-devel libgnomeui-devel git svn libtool

cd /usr/src

git clone git://github.com/mono/gnome-sharp

cd gnome-sharp

./bootstrap-2.24 --prefix=/opt/mono

make && make install
```

But the gtk2 and the installs after fails:

checking for MONO_DEPENDENCY... yes
checking for gacutil... no
configure: error: No gacutil tool found. You need to install either the mono or .Net SDK.

The same with bootstrap...

How could i fix it?

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
    # cd /usr/src/gtk-sharp-2.12.21
    # export PATH=$PATH:/opt/mono/bin
    # export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/mono/lib/pkgconfig
    # ./configure --prefix=/opt/mono
    # make
    # make install
```